# wp trim function not working

Tags: posts, functions, query-posts, excerpt, limit

Ok i have this code currently.

```
<?php

query_posts('category_name=widgets2');

echo "<div id='widgets-wrapper2'><div id='marginwidgets' style='overflow: auto; max-    width: 100%; height: 450px; max-height: 100%; margin: 0 auto;'>";
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
echo "<div class='thewidgets2'>";

echo wp_trim_words( the_content(), $num_words = 0, $more = "..." );

echo '<div style="height: 20px;"></div><a class="button2"     href="'.get_permalink().'">Read More</a></div>';
endwhile;
echo "</div></div>";

?>
```

as you can see, it gets all the post from the category name widgets2 and then it should display it.

and this line

```
echo wp_trim_words( the_content(), $num_words = 100, $more = "..." );
```

should trim the words from the_content() to 100 and add a excerpt at the end character but unfortunately it doesnt work, instead it just display the entire contents that looks untrim at all.

Hope someone here could figured out. Im open in any suggestions, recommendations and all relevant ideas, thank you.

Comment: It's says `0` in your code example instead of `100`. Also you don't need variables in function call, just `echo wp_trim_words( the_content(), 100, '...' );`

Comment: possible duplicate of [limit the words in the post content and add read more link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69204/limit-the-words-in-the-post-content-and-add-read-more-link)

Comment: Why don't you simply stick to your old question? Comment, make progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) echoes post content. It does not return a string that you can manipulate. You need [`get_the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) Swap those functions and it should work.