# Limit the_excerpt with max of x characters

Tags: php, excerpt, limit

**What I'm trying to do:**
I want to display `the_excerpt`, but I have a maximum of `x` characters `the_excerpt` may use, but I don't want to display a couple of characters of a word, only whole words.

**Some more information:**
This code is on a non-single/non-permalink web page such as archives, categories, front page, and searches, that makes me unable to use `<!--more-->`.

**The code:**
This is the code I use:

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', function( ) {
    return 20;
} );

if ( have_posts() ):
    while( have_posts() ): the_post();
        the_excerpt( );
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [limit the words in the post content and add read more link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69204/limit-the-words-in-the-post-content-and-add-read-more-link)

Comment: Try to implement this solution in the filter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233290/making-sure-php-substr-finishes-on-a-word-not-a-character

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter('wp_trim_excerpt', function($text){    
   $max_length = 140;

   if(mb_strlen($text, 'UTF-8') > $max_length){
     $split_pos = mb_strpos(wordwrap($text, $max_length), "\n", 0, 'UTF-8');
     $text = mb_substr($text, 0, $split_pos, 'UTF-8');
   }

   return $text;
});
```

This should take into account your max length and split the text at the nearest word boundary.
Apply the filter, and call `the_excerpt();` in your templates

---

Apparently there's a [`wp_trim_words`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words) function from WP 3.3 that you can also use, but from the source looks very inefficient. Appart from using 3 regexes, it splits the text into an array of words, and this can get very slow and memory exhaustive for large chunks of text...

Answer (score 0):

After some puzzling, I found this solution:

```
$limit_characters = 120;

function new_excerpt_length( ) {
    global $length;
    return $length;
}

function get_the_excerpt_special( ) {
    global $limit_characters, $length;

    if(strlen( get_the_excerpt() ) > $limit_characters ) {
        $length--;
        return get_the_excerpt_special();
    } else {
        the_excerpt();
    }
}

if ( have_posts() ):
    while( have_posts() ): the_post();
        add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length' );

        $length = 20;
        get_the_excerpt_special( );

        remove_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length' );

    endwhile;
endif;
```

It works! YAY! But since it has to repeatably call `get_the_excerpt`, the page slows down a bit.

Comment: This cannot work. Your code will break multibyte characters. See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/11089/73) for proper truncating.

Comment: [Another answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69204/limit-the-words-in-the-post-content-and-add-read-more-link) that limits the amount of _words_.