# Limit number of characters in different excerpts

Tags: functions, excerpt

I've been using this little snippet from [another answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91015/33310) on here to limit the number of characters that display in the excerpt;

```
add_filter('wp_trim_excerpt', function($text){    
    $max_length = 140;
    if(mb_strlen($text, 'UTF-8') > $max_length){
        $split_pos = mb_strpos(wordwrap($text, $max_length), "\n", 0, 'UTF-8');
        $text = mb_substr($text, 0, $split_pos, 'UTF-8');
    }

    return $text;
});
```

The problem is that I now have multiple excerpts and one global character limit isn't a viable option anymore.

Is there a way that I could define the character limit on individual excerpts? (So, for example, one excerpt could show 150 characters while another shows 200?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following code into `functions.php`:

```
// TRUNCK STRING TO SHORT THE STRINGS
function trunck_string($str = "", $len = 150, $more = 'true') {

    if ($str == "") return $str;
    if (is_array($str)) return $str;
    $str = strip_tags($str);    
    $str = trim($str);
    // if it's les than the size given, then return it

    if (strlen($str) <= $len) return $str;

    // else get that size of text
    $str = substr($str, 0, $len);
    // backtrack to the end of a word
    if ($str != "") {
      // check to see if there are any spaces left
      if (!substr_count($str , " ")) {
        if ($more == 'true') $str .= "...";
        return $str;
      }
      // backtrack
      while(strlen($str) && ($str[strlen($str)-1] != " ")) {
        $str = substr($str, 0, -1);
      }
      $str = substr($str, 0, -1);
      if ($more == 'true') $str .= "...";
      if ($more != 'true' and $more != 'false') $str .= $more;
    }
    return $str;
}


// the_content() WITHOUT IMAGES
// GET the_content() BUT EXCLUDE <img> OR <img/> TAGS THEN ECHO the_content()
// And ADD <a>DETAILS</a>
function custom_excerpt( $Trunckvalue = null ) {
    ob_start();
    the_content();
    $postOutput = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', ob_get_contents());
    ob_end_clean();
    echo trunck_string( $postOutput, $Trunckvalue, true ); ?>
    <a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark">DETAILS</a>
    <?php
}
```

Now everything required is **ready**.

#### EXPLANATION

As you can understand, in the second or last function we are taking `the_content()` and excluding the `<img/>` tags, so that they will appear as `the_excerpt()`. And then we are passing the trunck value into the new custom excerpt. And using the `custom_excerpt()` function anywhere we can use our new excerpt.

#### USAGE

Just where you need to call the `<?php the_excerpt() ?>`, simply call the `<?php custom_excerpt() ?>`. If you want to control the excerpt length, just put the length in number like: `<?php custom_excerpt(250) ?>`.