# How to set up a post word limit for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm not trying to set the exerpt for a custom post type, but a word limit in the admin of my custom post type.

I have just set up a custom post type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'test_post_type' ); 
function create_post_type() 
    register_post_type( 
       'test_post_type',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'test' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'test' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

I would like to find out how to set a word limit for this custom post type, so when the publish button is clicked, it will display an error due to the amount of words going over the word limit.

I only know how to set up a word limit for the title on all posts:

```
function maxWord($title){
global $post;
$title = $post->post_title;
if (str_word_count($title) >= 15 ) // maximum of 15 words
    wp_die( __('Your post title is over the maximum word count.') );
} 
add_action('publish_post', 'maxWord');
```

I would like it the same as above, but a word limit on the tinymce post in my custom post type only.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: @kaiser not a duplicate. the question you linked to is about limiting the post content when displayed on front end.  Andy wants to limit the content entered by editor/admin in the WP admin editor window, so when they hit Publish/Save, they get an error message if content limit is reached.

Answer (score 1):

### Filters and Actions

The hooks you can chose to run whatever limits the post content length from, is either `save_post`, `save_post_{post_type}` or `edit_post` (or both) (the following actions are executed inside [`wp_publish_post()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/48620242c4571631c6f13dc8ef37dfda4b0cd9a9/wp-includes/post.php#L3584-L3612)

```
/** This action is documented in wp-includes/post.php */
do_action( 'edit_post', $post->ID, $post );
do_action( "save_post_{$post->post_type}", $post->ID, $post, true );
do_action( 'save_post', $post->ID, $post, true );
do_action( 'wp_insert_post', $post->ID, $post, true );
```

*or* one of the post transition hooks executing inside [`wp_transition_post_status()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0/wp-includes/post.php#L3928). Namely those are:

```
do_action( 'transition_post_status', $new_status, $old_status, $post );
do_action( "{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}", $post );
do_action( "{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}", $post_id, $post );
```

To check inside a callback on an filter or action if you are on the correct filter, you can use `current_filter()` or `current_action()` (where later is just a wrapper for `current_filter()`), which returns a string with the name of the filter or action currently running.

### Limits

To *limit* the amount of words, you may want to use

```
wp_trim_words( $content, 300 );
```

to limit the content to for e.g. 300 words.

There is more to it when there is already content present. To get around this, you can [leverage the plugins in this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/69215/385) I wrote to limit excerpt length. Just alter it if you want to run it on the content only.

The general idea (in pseudo code) always is:

```
Explode the string of words in an array on empty space
Count the number of array items
If they exceed $limit, loop through them or slice the array
Return everything below and equal to the threshold
```

#### Core API

The reason why you may want to use [`wp_trim_words()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2582-L2616) instead of a simple loop is, that it strips all HTML tags from a string (so they don't add to the count) and that there is a filter running callbacks before the result is returned, allowing for a very fine grained and targetted approach

```
apply_filters( 'wp_trim_words', $text, $num_words, $more, $original_text );
```

### Putting a plugin together

Just fill in whatever you may want to do. Make sure that you inform the user properly by using something like [`post_updated_messages`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/8c3027c3c7f542218b23caef4086f3b4ab2cea15/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php#L105) to tell the user why you stripped off words, refused to save the content or whatever UX you want deliver

```
<?php 
/** Plugin Name: WPSE (#172544) Limit Content by Word Count */

add_action( 'save_post_test_post_type', function( $id, \WP_Post $post, $updated ) 
{
    # debug:
    # var_dump( $post, $_POST );
    // Here you can do whatever you want to do to limit the 
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kaiser, that is impressive. Thanks for unmarking this as a duplicate, I wasn't going to because I didn't think anyone would know how to do it. I'll follow your guide and try to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would not recommend making any such changes to the default way the Wordpress editor works as it could pose issues in the future.

However, I think you may be able to accomplish this with some Javascript/jQuery.

[Take a look at this example.](http://kaspars.net/blog/wordpress/limit-number-words-characters-in-wordpress-editor) Make sure to test suggested implementation thoroughly, I have not tested it.

Comment: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, that link looks interesting, I'll see if I can get it to work.